# Mounting a unmounted USB drive

Tags: 14.04, gparted

I have unmounted my USB drive using Gparted. But then I remove the USB drive from computer and reconnect, it is not visible in my computer. How can i make it visible??

Here is the output from `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 245.4G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0  97.7G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 120.9G  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7.6G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lsblk` to identify the drive name, then moun tit with:
`[sudo] mount /dev/sdxX /your/mountpoint`

Comment: What will be in `your` and `mountpoint` field?

Comment: The path where you want to mount it. (e.g. /media/external). If you dont have a folder to mount it to already just create it with `mkdir /media/external`

Comment: I have given here the output for `lsblk`. Would you tell me what should I wtite in terminal?

Comment: Assuming sdb is your 8GB external drive and you want to mount it to /media/external: `mkdir /media/external` then `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external`. But the drive has no partition, you have to create a partition first. (`sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb`). Was there no partition/data on the stick?

Comment: `scotia@scotia-desktop:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external`
`mount: mount point /media/external does not exist`

Comment: `/media/external` does not exists. Sorry I forgot the sudo, you have to run `sudo mkdir /media/external`

Comment: `scotia@scotia-desktop:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external`
`mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist`

Comment: Have you create the partition on sdb? If your run `lsblk` there should be a sdb1 listed unter sdb. Else you have to create the partition first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15354/discussion-between-scotia--and-pabi).

Comment: Sorry I was busy this weekend. Tell me if you still got problems.